# Raspian wont boot into GUI

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I don’t know what happened but my raspberry pi won’t boot up to a GUI anymore. All I get is a command line with a picture that says welcome to the raspberry pi desktop. Any idea what went wrong? This is my screen.  [image]

Comment: did you try to use the config tool "raspi-config" from console? There there is an option to select how you want to boot: to console or to graphical desktop, either using passwor or with auto-login.

Comment: Yes did that it still loads only to the command line

Comment: Is your disk space full ? It could be the reason.

Comment: Ops, sorry, I didn't see the screenshot properly, your are out of space and lxde can't start

Comment: Ok, should I got in by SSH and delete stuff?

Comment: In case you use it to store videos, audios, etc, you should delete stuff. You may also think on having a look to the log files.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your Raspberry PI disk is full and there is not enough space to start LXDE.

You can try deleting files from your home directory and also trying to find other kind of files like big Log files.
You can use the following command to find files bigger than a certain amount of MB:

```
find /home/ -type f -size +50M
```

The command above will list files bigger than 50MB

Comment: Thx I’m back in,